# "no longer needed" flag on chatty comment declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged a comment as "no longer needed", and the flag got declined. The thing is, the comment wasn't really obsolete, but rather a bit too chatty. I don't want to target the comment here, so I won't link to it. The exact timestamp of the flag is `2018-06-15 10:25:31Z`.

I think the confusion might have arisen from how the flag is called, "no **longer** needed". Its description is:

> This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.

I've read ([1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14120/41024), [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8609/41024)), but my case is different. First of all, my case isn't a flagging spree, as in the second case. Second, the comment itself isn't a reply to a non-obsolete comment, as in the first case, but it feels like it could very easily ignite some chat in the comment section. Also, it wasn't an old comment, but a new one posted in the same day as I flagged it.

What were the reasons behind declining the flag, if any? The reason I'm asking is because I can't fully understand why the flag was declined.

Comment: Then do you think that it should be deleted?

Comment: Based on "feels like it could very easily ignite some chat in the comment section", are you using that as your definition for "chatty"? I can't say whether that is correct or not, but it isn't how I would define chatty and could be part of the confusion.

Comment: @KamilDrakari No, that's not really my definition of "chatty". I define a chatty comment as a comment which invites discussion unrelated to the post it's on, however I don't flag all chatty comments. The one I'm referring too seemed exceptional to me, so I flagged it.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer that definition still seems pretty far from the definition I would use for chatty (for me it's basically "does not encourage or contribute to discussion at all"), which remains a potential disagreement. That said, without seeing the comment in question it's tough to evaluate against slight nuances in definitions.